# Getting Error while accessing wsimport in Webservice

Tags: web-services, soap, wsimport

Getting the below Error while importing an WSDL, I am new to this please guide me what i need to do

> [ERROR] com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2;
>   www.webservicex.net
>
> Failed to read the WSDL document:
>   http://www.webservicex.net/sunsetriseservice.a smx?WSDL, because 1)
>   could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3)
>   the root element of the document is not .
>
> [ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided
>   WSDL(s):
>
> At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be
>   provided.
>
> Failed to parse the WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when using `wsimport`, specifically specifying the HTTP URL for the WSDL. The solution I found was to download the WSDL and save it locally; `wsimport` was able to use it fine.

I'm not sure why, but specifying the HTTP URL for the WSDL and running with the `-verbose` option also solved it.